# Selenium scraped data to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

It is my first attempt for scraping with selenium.

I collected what I want but I want to pass it to pandas dataframe in order to make some calculations.

below sample code is how I get the data;

(it is a financial data and [2] and [3] represents years(2016,2017) respectively)

```
nf1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tbodyMTablo"]/tr[84]/td[2]').text
nf2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tbodyMTablo"]/tr[84]/td[3]').text

do_v1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tbodyMTablo"]/tr[2]/td[2]').text
do_v2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tbodyMTablo"]/tr[2]/td[3]').text

kvb_1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tbodyMTablo"]/tr[29]/td[2]').text
kvb_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tbodyMTablo"]/tr[29]/td[3]').text
```

It is a numerical data but stored as str(probably because of .text) and `int(nf2)`  or `float(nf2`) didn't work.

Is there any way to store as values in first place?
( without `.text` it returns 0)

What is the proper way to scrape numerical data and store it in dataframe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: call float() or int() on the .text property of the WebElement your method returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using .get_attribute('innerHTML') instead of .text

---

edit*

---

It seems that you are trying to convert selenium object into int(). but int requires a string to convert(that contains only numbers).

So, you can try to convert it like this.

**"this example is about scraping a number inside of a field on a random page on Wikipedia; try to adapt it to your code."**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet#Nascita_del_World_Wide_Web_.281991.29')

scraped = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="tocnumber" and contains(text(), "1")]')

print(int(scraped.get_attribute('innerHTML')))

driver.quit()
```

Comment: it gives the same result (stored as str)

Comment: the value inside nf1 and nf2 contains only numbers or also letters? 
also have you tried to strip() before converting it to int()?
for example: int(nf1.strip())

Comment: only numbers, i get this error; 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-7.402.508'

Comment: can you please link the page you are trying to scrape from, so maybe I can help better.

Comment: Hello again, I solved this by refreshing, probably I tried to scrap it before it loads.